# How to keep score correctly

Tags: java

The program is being designed to give a point every time a keyword is recognized, but is not doing so. I am sure the fix is quite simple but is escaping me.

I also need this to display when no keywords were detected. Eventually I would like to be able to hardcode values to each keyword dependent on importance.Instead of just one point per word.

```
import java.util.*;

public class KeyWords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String who = null, what = null, where = null, when = null,
                why = null, how = null;

        String[] keywords = {"who", "what", "where", "when", "why", "how"};

        int RunningTotal = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a sentence\n");
        String input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        for (String keyword : keywords) {
            if (input.contains(keyword)) {
                System.out.println("Found keyword: " + keyword);
            }

            switch (keyword) {
                case "who":
                    RunningTotal++;
                    break;
                case "what":
                    RunningTotal++;
                    break;
                case "where":
                    RunningTotal++;
                    break;
                case "when":
                    RunningTotal++;
                    break;
                case "why":
                    RunningTotal++;
                    break;
                case "how":
                    RunningTotal++;//Broken, always adds all 6
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("No keywords detected...");//Does not work
            }
        }//for loop

        System.out.println(RunningTotal);
        if (RunningTotal <= 3) {
            System.out.println("Lack of communication skills");
        }
    }

}//class
```

Comment: Move the `switch` to inside the `if`.

Comment: what is the point of having `break` ?

Comment: May be its a good time to learn how to debug your source code in Java

Comment: You are looping over your keyword list to see if it contains your keywords... so yes, of course it contains all your keywords.  Try looping over the words in your input sentence instead.

Comment: Hint: you want us to spend our time to help you with your problem. So you please spend the one minute it takes to properly indent all of your code.

Answer (score 3):

If you go to the switch statement, you will see that you are evaluating the keyword extracted from your keyword list.

I will suggest you to get rid of the switch statement. It is useless. You can just use the if statement that you have inside of the loop to do the same. I won't provide the code, but I think that it is a huge hint.

Answer (score 2):

Switch statement is getting executed for every keyword, even if it does not match. Just put the switch statement inside the if and it should give you expected result. Have you tried eclipse and eclipse debugging, it would make your job easy to find these problems yourself.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do not do something like

```
String who = null, what = null, where = null, when = null,
                why = null, how = null;
```

This is awful for Java Developers. This kind of code is reconized of structured languages like C.

Well I see you're getting the `String input` and verifying if it contains the `keyword` from the array. You shall inverse it, and if you couldn't find the `keyword` inside the array, you should avoid the method. I have rewrited your code, so take a look if this can solve your problem:

```
import java.util.*;

public class KeyWords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> keywords = Arrays.asList("who", "what", "where", "when", "why", "how");

        int RunningTotal = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a sentence\n");
        String input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        if (!keywords.contains(input.trim().toLowerCase())) {
            System.out.println("No keywords detected...");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Found keyword: " + input);

            switch (input) {
                case "who":
                    RunningTotal++;
                    break;
                case "what":
                    RunningTotal++;
                    break;
                case "where":
                    RunningTotal++;
                    break;
                case "when":
                    RunningTotal++;
                    break;
                case "why":
                    RunningTotal++;
                    break;
                case "how":
                    RunningTotal++;//Broken, always adds all 6
                    break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(RunningTotal);
        if (RunningTotal <= 3) {
            System.out.println("Lack of communication skills");
        }
    }

}//class
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need that switch statement at all. Try this and let me know if it had resolved your issue:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] keywords = {"who", "what", "where", "when", "why", "how"};

    int keywordsFound = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a sentence");
    String input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();

    for (String keyword : keywords) {
        if (input.contains(keyword)) {
            keywordsFound++;
            System.out.println("Found keyword: " + keyword);
        }
    }//for loop

    System.out.printf("Found %d keywords\n", keywordsFound);
    if (keywordsFound <= 3) {
        System.out.println("Lack of communication skills");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,
I removed the switch statement entirely and placed everything in the for loop. The following code was used:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] keywords = {"who", "what", "where", "when", "why", "how"};

    int keywordsFound = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a sentence");
    String input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();

    for (String keyword : keywords) {
        if (input.contains(keyword)) {
            keywordsFound++;
            System.out.println("Found keyword: " + keyword);
        }
    }//for loop

    System.out.printf("Found %d keywords\n", keywordsFound);
    if (keywordsFound <= 3) {
        System.out.println("Lack of communication skills");
    }
}
```